# silver bronze linear optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

A non-profit offers crafts complimentary gift packages for its donors. The non-profit costs for each package are \$4  for  the Bronze level package, \$7 for the Silver level package, and \$9 for the Gold level package. They have to use at least 45 coffee mugs in the packages they produce.

Each Bronze package contains 2 coffee mugs, each Silver package contains 3 coffee mugs, and each Gold package contains 4 coffee mugs. In addition, they have to use at least 40 pens.

Each Bronze package has 1 pen, each Silver package has 5 pens, and each Gold package has 2 pens. How many of each package should be made to minimize their cost? What is the minimum cost?

Is the answer for this, upon calculating, 95? that is 15 bronze and 5 silver only? I used the simplex algorithm method for solving

Comment: Yes, the solution is correct. ;)

Comment: Do you have a more specific question ?

Comment: Yes - could you do phase 2 of this? setting up and showing the linear algebra and steps. thanks

Comment: @callculus, so your answer from doing the above, was it 95? And 15 bronze and 5 silver only?

Comment: Yes, and no Gold. The value of 95 can be calculated by plugging in the values 15,5 and 0 into the objective function. You can check if the constraints are O.K. as well. Have you done Phase 0 and Phase 1 ?

Comment: I was stuck on this part, and can you set it up and show me those steps?

Comment: Show me (us) where you stuck then we can go on.